# Table not looking good tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm trying to make a table in Latex but I'm not expert in it and it's not looking good.
Below is what I did but the result is not fitted and not looking good so if anyone could please how I can correctly format it:

```
\begin{table}
\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.3\tabcolsep}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*2{>{\centering\hsize=1.6666\hsize}X|}*8{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.94444\hsize}X|}}
\hline
{\bf frfrfrfrf \textbackslash Point of Comparison} & {\bf Figure} & {\bf C-asasaseed} & {\bf A-asasaseed} & {\bf B-asasaseed} & {\bf Average asasaseed} & {\bf frfrfr} & {\bf Runtime}\\
\hline
hrhrheh (frwsrty sewcftyhd adrfraed) & Fig. 4a & 2.4216 & 2.2576 & 1.9949 & 2.2247 & $\mathcal{O}( n \times K * I * d )$ & 11 sec\\
\hline
fdfrfrf (hekko hdjek hsnejtls) & Fig. 4b &  2.4285 & 2.2496 & 1.9969 & 2.2250 & $\mathcal{O}( n * K * I * d )$ & 10 sec \\
\hline
bvgrfsf (nshehe sdf fdesf) & Fig. 4c & 2.4264 & 2.2520 & 1.9995 & 2.2260 & $\mathcal{O}( n * K * I * d )$ & 13 sec \\
\hline
asds A-ascsc & Fig. 4d & 2.1011 & 2.2388 & 1.9540 & 2.0980 & $\mathcal{O}(n * K * I)$ & 1 sec \\
\hline
      A-edede++ & Fig. 4e & 2.4570 & 2.2214 & 1.9937 & 2.2240 & $\mathcal{O}(\log{K})$ & 1 sec \\
\hline
    A-dedede & Fig. 4f & 2.3168 & 2.2255 & 1.9899 & 2.1774 & $\mathcal{O}(I * K * (n-K)^2)$ & 5 sec \\
\hline
asssse C-sdesd & Fig. 4g & 2.4033 & 2.2552 & 1.9991 & 2.2192 & $\mathcal{O}(n * d * K^2 * i)$ & 5 sec \\
\hline
 frfrf frfrfrfrfr frfrfrfrf & Fig. 4h & 2.4813 & 2.2187 & 1.9863 & 2.2288 & $\mathcal{O}(n * d * K^2 * i)$ & 312 sec\\
\hline
 dedededededed ededededededed sjsjsjsjsjs & Fig. 4i & 2.1853 & 1.9593 & 1.9593 & 2.0347 & $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ & 7 sec \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{jnflkrnflref rfref gregergedi  efreffe frefref frefref fr frfr frfrfrf frfrr frfr.}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table}
```

and this is how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: And what is your question? You need to tell us what you're after.

Comment: @PaulGessler I need it to be formatted correctly so that it looks and good and fits. Have you tried it?

Comment: "Looking good" is subjective, and we can't know if it fits or not until we know your `\documentclass` and margin settings. And no, I haven't tried it, because it's not a complete MWE.

Comment: @shepherd you have not made it easy for people to try as you have only posted a fragment. Note `\bf` has been deprecated in latex since latex2e released back in 1993. Generally speaking I wouldn't recommend `tabularx` for numerical data (it is not intended for that) just use `tabular` and align the numbers using `siunitx` or `dcolumn` packages which define numeric column types

Comment: @PaulGessler I edited my question and added a screenshot of the result, so if you could please advise.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your comment. It not only hold numerical data, it holds some text as well, I'd appreciate if you can advise as I'm not a prof. in latex tables.

Comment: See the previous comments: you need to make a reasonable example. Actually I'm just about done tonight but someone in a better timezone would no doubt help, but I'd read the booktabs documentation (and remove all the rules) and use tabular not tabularx, the table would look much better. That is the example needs to be `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` if only to specify the width in which you need to fit the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- The column type of the second column may as well be set to `c` to minimize its width
- For the remaining seven columns, a ratio of widths of roughly 3:2 seems about right. Setting the `\hsize` of the left-most column to `1.3` and that of the other six to `0.95` (note: 1.3 + 6*0.95 = 7) may be a good starting point. Feel free to fine-tune these parameters.
- Use `\RaggedRight` and `\Centering` (macros provided by the `ragged2e` package) to allow LaTeX to hyphenate the column contents. Add explicit discretionaries (`\-`) where needed. Unsurprisingly, LaTeX doesn't "know" how to hyphenate longish strings such as "ededededededed".
- In column 2, replace all instances of `Fig.` with `Fig.\` to inform LaTeX that these periods ("full stops") aren't of the sentence-ending variety. Saves some more space...
- Last but not least, omit all vertical rules, replace some of the `\hline`s with the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, and replace all other horizontal lines with `\addlinespace`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.35\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\Centering\hsize=.95\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
%\centering  %% not needed
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{.4\tabcolsep}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} Y c *{7}{Z} @{}}
\toprule
\bfseries frfrfrfrf \textbackslash Point of Comparison & 
\bfseries Figure & 
\bfseries C-asasa\-seed & 
\bfseries A-asasa\-seed & 
\bfseries B-asasa\-seed & 
\bfseries Aver\-age asasa\-seed & 
\bfseries frfrfr & 
\bfseries Run\-time\\
\midrule
hrhrheh (frwsrty sewcftyhd adrfraed) & Fig.\ 4a & 2.4216 & 2.2576 & 1.9949 & 2.2247 & $\mathcal{O}( n \times K * I * d )$ & 11 sec\\
\addlinespace
fdfrfrf (hekko hdjek hsnejtls) & Fig.\ 4b &  2.4285 & 2.2496 & 1.9969 & 2.2250 & $\mathcal{O}( n * K * I * d )$ & 10 sec \\
\addlinespace
bvgrfsf (nshehe sdf fdesf) & Fig.\ 4c & 2.4264 & 2.2520 & 1.9995 & 2.2260 & $\mathcal{O}( n * K * I * d )$ & 13 sec \\
\addlinespace
asds A-ascsc & Fig.\ 4d & 2.1011 & 2.2388 & 1.9540 & 2.0980 & $\mathcal{O}(n * K * I)$ & 1 sec \\
\addlinespace
A-ede\-de++ & Fig.\ 4e & 2.4570 & 2.2214 & 1.9937 & 2.2240 & $\mathcal{O}(\log{K})$ & 1 sec \\
\addlinespace
    A-dedede & Fig.\ 4f & 2.3168 & 2.2255 & 1.9899 & 2.1774 & $\mathcal{O}(I * K * (n-K)^2)$ & 5 sec \\
\addlinespace
asssse C-sdesd & Fig.\ 4g & 2.4033 & 2.2552 & 1.9991 & 2.2192 & $\mathcal{O}(n * d * K^2 * i)$ & 5 sec \\
\addlinespace
 frfrf frfrfrfrfr frfrfrfrf & Fig.\ 4h & 2.4813 & 2.2187 & 1.9863 & 2.2288 & $\mathcal{O}(n * d * K^2 * i)$ & 312 sec\\
\addlinespace
 dededede\-deded ededede\-dededed sjsjsjsjsjs & Fig.\ 4i & 2.1853 & 1.9593 & 1.9593 & 2.0347 & $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ & 7 sec \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{jnflkrnflref rfref gregergedi  efreffe frefref frefref fr frfr frfrfrf frfrr frfr.}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another attempt. Without the text, I can't really be sure the layout adjustments I've made make much sense, but here goes anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.7pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}%
  {>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xc*4{S[table-format=1.4]}>{$}c<{$}S[table-format=3.0]@{}}
\toprule
\hfill frfrfrfrf                         & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{asasaseed} & \text{frfrfr}  & {Runtime} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6}
Pt.~of Comparison                        & Fig. & {C} & {A} & {B} & {Avg.} & \mathcal{O}(\;)    & {(s)} \\
\midrule
hrhrheh (frwsrty sewcftyhd adrfraed)     & 4a   & 2.4216 & 2.2576 & 1.9949 & 2.2247 & n K I d     &  11 \\
fdfrfrf (hekko hdjek hsnejtls)           & 4b   & 2.4285 & 2.2496 & 1.9969 & 2.2250 & n K I d     &  10 \\
bvgrfsf (nshehe sdf fdesf)               & 4c   & 2.4264 & 2.2520 & 1.9995 & 2.2260 & n K I d     &  13 \\
asds A-ascsc                             & 4d   & 2.1011 & 2.2388 & 1.9540 & 2.0980 & n K I       &   1 \\
A-edede++                                & 4e   & 2.4570 & 2.2214 & 1.9937 & 2.2240 & \log{K}     &   1 \\
A-dedede                                 & 4f   & 2.3168 & 2.2255 & 1.9899 & 2.1774 & I K (n-K)^2 &   5 \\
asssse C-sdesd                           & 4g   & 2.4033 & 2.2552 & 1.9991 & 2.2192 & n d K^2 i   &   5 \\
frfrf frfrfrfrfr frfrfrfrf               & 4h   & 2.4813 & 2.2187 & 1.9863 & 2.2288 & n d K^2 i   & 312 \\
dedededededed ededededededed sjsjsjsjsjs & 4i   & 2.1853 & 1.9593 & 1.9593 & 2.0347 & n^2         &   7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{jnflkrnflref rfref gregergedi  efreffe frefref frefref fr frfr frfrfrf frfrr frfr.}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

How about that? I suppressed all vertical rules, loaded booktabs and cellspace for a better vertical spacing between rows. I also used `siunitx`for numbers alignment and `makecell`, which allows for line breaks and a common formatting of column heads.

```
%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.4\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=0.9\hsize}X}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{Y}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small\centering\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{C{Y}c*4{Z}@{}c@{}S[table-format = 2]}
\bottomrule
\thead{frfrfrfrf \textbackslash Point\\ of Comparison} & \thead{Figure} & \thead{C-\\asasaseed} & \thead{A-\\asasaseed} & \thead{B-\\asasaseed} & \thead{Average\\ asasaseed} & \thead{frfrfr} & {\thead{Runtime\\\mdseries(s)}} \\
\addlinespace[-1ex]
\midrule
hrhrheh (frwsrty sewcftyhd adrfraed) & Fig. 4a & 2.4216 & 2.2576 & 1.9949 & 2.2247 & $\mathcal{O}( n \times K * I * d )$ & 11 \\
fdfrfrf (hekko hdjek hsnejtls) & Fig. 4b & 2.4285 & 2.2496 & 1.9969 & 2.2250 & $\mathcal{O}( n * K * I * d )$ & 10 \\
bvgrfsf (nshehe sdf fdesf) & Fig. 4c & 2.4264 & 2.2520 & 1.9995 & 2.2260 & $\mathcal{O}( n * K * I * d )$ & 13 \\
asds A-ascsc & Fig. 4d & 2.1011 & 2.2388 & 1.9540 & 2.0980 & $\mathcal{O}(n * K * I)$ & 1 \\
  A-edede++ & Fig. 4e & 2.4570 & 2.2214 & 1.9937 & 2.2240 & $\mathcal{O}(\log{K})$ & 1 \\
A-dedede & Fig. 4f & 2.3168 & 2.2255 & 1.9899 & 2.1774 & $\mathcal{O}(I * K * (n-K)^2)$ & 5 \\
asssse C-sdesd & Fig. 4g & 2.4033 & 2.2552 & 1.9991 & 2.2192 & $\mathcal{O}(n * d * K^2 * i)$ & 5 \\
frfrf frfrfrfrfr frfrfrfrf & Fig. 4h & 2.4813 & 2.2187 & 1.9863 & 2.2288 & $\mathcal{O}(n * d * K^2 * i)$ & 312 \\
dedededededed ededededededed sjsjsjsjsjs & Fig. 4i & 2.1853 & 1.9593 & 1.9593 & 2.0347 & $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ & 7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{jnflkrnflref rfref gregergedi efreffe frefref frefref fr frfr frfrfrf frfrr frfr.}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: right (not ragged, nor Ragged…). As it was a fake text I didn't pay too much attention to this point. I'll add it. Thanks for pointing that.